# Android studio doesn't find my virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio

I've tried with multiple device but in any condition when i run the application android studio opens the *edit configuration* tab with an error: *Pleas select android SDK*. So i navigate trought all tabs but nothing. Nothing where i can put an SDK or use my virtual device.

Comment: Can you inlude screenshot of what you have tried so far and your error?

Comment: Have you do a Gradle sync ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the issue has to do with an error within the AVD Manager. I would suggest that you uninstall the AVD (Virtual Devices) SDK and then reinstall it completely, and see whether it helps to sort out your issue.

To uninstall/install the AVD Manager, go to **Tools > SDK Manager > Android SDK** and select the **SDK Tools** Tab. Then scroll down until you find the **Android AVD/Virtual Devices SDK**.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your developer options on the device and enable debuging form there.